# how to add country column in prestashop AdminCustomersControllerCore

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

i want to add an extra column in AdminCustomersControllerCore so that it will show a new column in my back office manage customer page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the hook `actionControllerNameListingFieldsModifier` to add fields.

Every admin controller calls this hook before generating the list/table.

```
Hook::exec('action'.$this->controller_name.'ListingFieldsModifier', array(
    'select' => &$this->_select,
    'join' => &$this->_join,
    'where' => &$this->_where,
    'group_by' => &$this->_group,
    'order_by' => &$this->_orderBy,
    'order_way' => &$this->_orderWay,
    'fields' => &$this->fields_list,
));
```

You will need to modify `select` and `fields` variable to include your own. You might need to modify `join` variable as well if you have data in a custom table.

Comment: @TECHNOSEO And with this hook you can do what you want.